# Event Fires only from the second time

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, event-handling, keydown

Have a textbox type column 'Qty', in a gridview that has to accept only numbers.The foll. code works good but only from the second input. I only want to use keydown here.

```
private void GridViewSale_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{     
  if (GridViewSale.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 4) //Allow only numbers for QTY column
    {
      TextBox Qty = e.Control as TextBox;
      Qty.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Qty_KeyDown);
    }
}
void Qty_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{         
  if ((e.KeyValue >= 48 && e.KeyValue <= 57) || (e.KeyValue >= 96 && e.KeyValue <= 105)//Allows numerics
    e.SuppressKeyPress = false;
  else
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;           
  }
```

1.Should I call the event handler at some place else like form_load.., to work for every input?
2. If I have to disable modifier inputs (SHIFT+1,SHIFT+2), how should I code that here?

Comment: One problem I find is that you are adding event handlers everytime which is bad. you should remove the handler first before adding, or check for null first..

Comment: Tried this but no luck..                                 Qty.KeyDown -= Qty_KeyDown;                                Qty.KeyDown += Qty_KeyDown;

Comment: I don't know what 48 and 57 corresponds to. but why dont u try `KeyCode` enum as such? like `if e.KeyCode== Keys.Shift` ... suppress ??

Comment: Thx for the posts. 48 - 57 is the range of values of num keys 0 -9; Tried if(e.KeyCode== Keys.Shift) e.SuppressKeyPress = true; But it still allows SHIFT+1.. it should be something like if(e.KeyCode== Keys.Shift+'numeric' key)

Comment: There's a missing bracket at the end of your `if`. Also you could use this instead. `e.SurpressKeyPress = !((e.KeyValue >= 48 && e.KeyValue <= 57) || (e.KeyValue >= 96 && e.KeyValue <= 105));`

Comment: Hi kschieck, tht didnt work out too. When I first select a cell in the Qty column and type it accepts any key and from the only the next input it starts to allow only nums. If I select the next cell, its the same again. I just want to not allow alpha right from first input..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason for this behaviour: Any keydown(char,num or symbol) for the first time is directly going to the 'EditingControlShowing' method instead of 'KeyDown'.So the input is already taken and hence the issue. I solved this with the foll. Workaround. (Replaced KeyDown with PreviewKeyDown & added CellBeginEdit,to check the key value before the cell enters Edit Mode:

```
private void GridViewSale_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
  {
    if (GridViewSale.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 4)//Allow only nums for QTY col.
          {
              TextBox Qty = e.Control as TextBox;
              Qty.KeyDown -= OnlyNums_KeyDown;
              Qty.KeyDown += OnlyNums_KeyDown;
          }
  }
private void GridViewSale_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
  {
     if ((e.KeyValue >= 48 && e.KeyValue <= 57) || (e.KeyValue >= 96 && e.KeyValue <= 105))
          {
              //Do Nothing
          }
          else
          {
              cancelEdit = true;
              GridViewSale.CellBeginEdit -= GridViewSale_CellBeginEdit;
              GridViewSale.CellBeginEdit += GridViewSale_CellBeginEdit;
          }
      }
private void GridViewSale_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
  {
      if (cancelEdit == true)
      {
          e.Cancel = true;
          cancelEdit = false;
      }
  }
```

[My 2nd Question still remains unaswered though].